# How do I display formatted XML in a SSRS Report?

Tags: xml, reporting-services

I have a field in my dataset that contains an unformatted XML string, for example:

```
<root><element><subelement>value</subelement></element></root>
```

How do I "prettify" it and display it within a Tablix control? Like this:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <subelement>value</subelement>
    </element>
</root>
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by using embedded code in the report and using `System.Xml.XmlTextWriter` with `XmlTextWriterSettings.Indent = true`

Open the Report Properties dialog and paste the following function in the Code tab:

```
Public Function FormatXml(input As String) As String
  Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
  doc.LoadXml(input)
  Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
  Dim settings As New System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings()
  settings.Indent = True
  settings.IndentChars = "    "      ' This includes 4 non-breaking spaces: ALT+0160
  settings.NewLineChars = System.Environment.NewLine
  settings.NewLineHandling = System.Xml.NewLineHandling.Replace
  settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = True
  Using writer As System.Xml.XmlWriter = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)
    doc.Save(writer)
  End Using
  Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

You will also need to add a reference to `System.Xml`, since it is not included by default. Select the 'References' tab in Report Properties, then add `System.Xml` from the .NET assemblies list:

```
System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Then, within the expression of your textbox/table, you can use the following expression:

```
=Code.FormatXml(Fields!YourXmlField.Value)
```

When you try and deploy the report, you may receive an error like:

```
The definition of the report '/your.report' is invalid. Line 0:, Column: 0
```

This error message is not very useful, but it likely means that your embedded code is incorrect in some way. The most common cause is that you're referencing a class that it can't find. For example, `XmlWriterSettings` instead of `System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings`.

Comment: This works great on my local host but it does not work when deployed to a remote server.  I'm not getting an error but the XML is not formatted.  I've found a lot of information about deploying custom assemblies in SSRS but nothing about troubleshooting the use of .NET assemblies.  Any ideas how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I notice that IE doesn't read the indentations at different depths, while Chrome and Mozilla do ( [screencap](http://imgur.com/6rEQWPB) ). I haven't debugged yet, but I'm wondering if you encountered this / have any tips? +1 for this in either case!!

Comment: side note : the XML has to be in a TXT BOX element..  and not inside a tablix.. this doesn't work inside a tablix which had me scratching my head for a while!