# XML in browser ssrs

Tags: xml, browser, reporting-services

I have a field in the database which is of type xml. I would like to show a sample image or a control on the report and ideally clicking the control should open the xml in a browser. Is it possible?

Comment: Unless the XML file is published in the server you cannot open a XML field from browser as a file in SSRS. I suggest you create a subreport and pass the XML field as parameter. When you click on an image in the main report the subreport opens with the XML data. If that meets your requeriment let me know.

Comment: Thanks. What control will i use in the sub report to show the xml?  Also will it be formatted?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674094/how-do-i-display-formatted-xml-in-a-ssrs-report):